# Placing the cells in a collection view in the centre rather than the outsides in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

By default, a collection view will attempt to space out the cells in the collection by spacing them evenly so that there will be one cell touching either side of the collection view. Example:
[image]

[image]

But, when the cell is too wide to fit multiple cells in one row on the collection view, it will centre the cell in the collection view.[image]

Is there a way to make the behaviour of centring cells, like in the 3rd picture, the default for the collection view so that there is 0 space between the individual cells and space on either side to the edges of the collection view?

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be to use a carefully set up something like

`let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: yourvalues, left: yourvalues, bottom: yourvalues, right: yourvalues)`,

and feed it to either `YourCollectionView.contentInset`, or

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
      return sectionInsets
  }
```

This should work! Lemme know if you have any troubles with it!

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. You should implement something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    CGFloat width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    return CGSize(width, anyHeight)
}
```

and then implement the delegate method below as well:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

Make sure to implement rotation handling too if it's applicable.